# Convert raster image to high resolution images

Tags: vb.net, graphics, picturebox

In the picture, it is clear that the writings are not checkered, but the arcs and circles that I draw are checkered
What should I do to prevent it from happening?

I posted a picture showing my problem

Please See It :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd5Yy.png)

I searched a lot for the solution, but I did not find the solution

I would be grateful if you could help me or give me keywords to find the solution

In the following, I will add my code
I wrote the program with Visual Basic

mycode :

```
    Dim Brush_Robot As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
    Dim Pen_Arc_Robot As Pen = New Pen(Color.Blue, 2)
    Dim rect_Robot As Rectangle
    Dim rect_Robot_Out_Line As Rectangle
    Dim Size_Robot As Size
    Dim Scale_GD As Integer = 100
Public Sub Draw_Robot(PicBox As PictureBox, Scale_GD As Short, Angle_Robot As Int16, IDText As String, Color_Back As Color, Color_Text As Color, Color_Robot As Color, Color_Center_Robot As Color, Color_Arc_Robot As Color, Color_Arc2_Robot As Color)
        Dim Graphic_Draw_Robot As Graphics
        Dim Graphic_Draw_Robot_BMP As Bitmap
        Size_Robot.Width = (Scale_GD * 0.8)
        Size_Robot.Height = (Scale_GD * 0.8)
        Graphic_Draw_Robot_BMP = New Bitmap(Size_Robot.Width - 1, Size_Robot.Height - 1)
        PicBox.Image = Graphic_Draw_Robot_BMP
        Graphic_Draw_Robot = Graphics.FromImage(PicBox.Image)
        Graphic_Draw_Robot.Clear(Color_Back)
        PicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        Brush_Robot.Color = Color_Robot
        rect_Robot.Location = New Point(-1, -1)
        rect_Robot.Size = Size_Robot
        Graphic_Draw_Robot.FillEllipse(Brush_Robot, rect_Robot)

        Size_Robot.Width = Scale_GD * 0.5
        Size_Robot.Height = Scale_GD * 0.5
        Brush_Robot.Color = Color_Center_Robot
        '=============================
        rect_Robot.Location = New Point((Scale_GD * 0.15) - 1, (Scale_GD * 0.15) - 1)
        '=============================
        rect_Robot.Size = Size_Robot
        Graphic_Draw_Robot.FillEllipse(Brush_Robot, rect_Robot)
        Pen_Arc_Robot.Color = Color_Arc_Robot
        Pen_Arc_Robot.Width = Scale_GD / 20
        Size_Robot.Width = Scale_GD * 0.7
        Size_Robot.Height = Scale_GD * 0.7
        rect_Robot_Out_Line.Location = New Point((Scale_GD * 0.05) - 1, (Scale_GD * 0.05) - 1)
        rect_Robot_Out_Line.Size = Size_Robot
        Graphic_Draw_Robot.DrawArc(Pen_Arc_Robot, rect_Robot_Out_Line, Angle_Robot - 50, 100)
        '--------------------------
        Pen_Arc_Robot.Color = Color_Arc2_Robot
        Pen_Arc_Robot.Width = Scale_GD / 30
        Size_Robot.Width = Scale_GD * 0.6
        Size_Robot.Height = Scale_GD * 0.6
        rect_Robot_Out_Line.Location = New Point((Scale_GD * 0.1) - 1, (Scale_GD * 0.1) - 1)
        rect_Robot_Out_Line.Size = Size_Robot
        Graphic_Draw_Robot.DrawArc(Pen_Arc_Robot, rect_Robot_Out_Line, Angle_Robot - 50, 100)
        '----------------------------
        Dim chosenFont As Font = New Font("Arial", CInt(Scale_GD * 0.2), FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim solidBrush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color_Text)
        Dim stringFormat As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical)
        Graphic_Draw_Robot.DrawString(IDText, chosenFont, solidBrush, (Scale_GD * 0.19) - 1, (Scale_GD * 0.25) - 1)
        PicBox.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Graphic_Draw_Robot.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`. Not good enough? Also set the `Graphic_Draw_Robot.SmoothingMode` to a value that makes you happy

Comment: This code solved my problem===>> Graphic_Draw_Robot.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias